# Sharing a context between AMQP callbacks

Tags: haskell, rabbitmq, amqp

There is a simple tutorial about RabbitMQ usage for Haskell where I took this piece of code

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
     conn <- openConnection "127.0.0.1" "/" "guest" "guest"
     ch   <- openChannel conn

     declareQueue ch newQueue {queueName       = "hello",
                               queueAutoDelete = False,
                               queueDurable    = False}

     putStrLn " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"
     consumeMsgs ch "hello" NoAck deliveryHandler

     -- waits for keypresses
     getLine
     closeConnection conn

deliveryHandler :: (Message, Envelope) -> IO ()
deliveryHandler (msg, metadata) =
  BL.putStrLn $ " [x] Received " <> msgBody msg
```

It simply explains how to get a message from the queue and process it with the callback.

The one thing might be simple to solve, but I'm struggling to understand how to add some mutable context inside the callback, so each time a function runs it can change it. Simply, how to calculate the message number in the queue order. I found that a possible solution is a State monad, is it?

And the second question - all these callbacks are processed in a parallel or not? If not, how to process them in parallel and keep the mutable context without a data race?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @bergey's answer - you can create a mutable reference such as an IORef or MVar.  These references can be passed to your handler using partial function application.  Typed but not tested code follows.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
     conn <- openConnection "127.0.0.1" "/" "guest" "guest"
     ch   <- openChannel conn
     ref  <- newMVar 0
```

Notice the `ref` in the above and the generating function `newMVar` from `Control.Concurrent.MVar`.

```
     declareQueue ch newQueue {queueName       = "hello",
                               queueAutoDelete = False,
                               queueDurable    = False}

     putStrLn " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"
     consumeMsgs ch "hello" NoAck (deliveryHandler ref)
```

See how we pass the ref to `deliveryHandler` by function application.

```
     -- waits for keypresses
     getLine
     closeConnection conn

deliveryHandler :: MVar Int -> (Message, Envelope) -> IO ()
deliveryHandler ref (msg, metadata) =
  BL.putStrLn $ " [x] Received " <> msgBody msg
  withMVar' ref $ \val ->
       do print val
          pure (val + 1)
```

And finally we can work with ref using function from `Control.Concurrent.MVar`, getting the old value and replacing it with a new value as desired.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to process multiple messages in parallel (in the same Haskell process) I would start with an [MVar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) to hold the shared state.

MVar is basically a shared variable with a lock, and a reasonable interface.  In simple cases (like a counter) that is enough to prevent data races.  It's a middle ground between lower-level (IORef) and higher-level (STM) abstractions over shared memory.  I think it's the easiest to understand, and I use it for all initial prototyping.

I don't know the RabbitMQ library, so can't answer your second question, about whether messages are processed in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for a response. MVar sounds a good fit for a parallel processing but in case of a single processing, what is the options to share mutable context between callbacks?

Comment: Since the type of `consumeMsgs` requires your callback to operate in IO, I'd stick to `MVar` even in the sequential case.  `IORef` would also be fine since you don't need a lock.  There's not much point to `StateT s IO` since that type doesn't provide any assurance that there are no mutable variables outside of s.  Building a more flexible / effect-save interface is possible but probably a bigger project than you are looking for.